# t test comparing one row (reference sample) to all other rows in the data frame

Tags: r, loops, row, t-test

I have a subset of my data below (dataset). It summarizes cell viability after treating the cells with different drugs (the actual dataset has 1200 drugs). The experiment was done in triplicates (samples1, 2, and 3). For the sake of simplicity I generated a small dataset below:

```
             sample_01        sample02         sample03
untreated    100                120                110
drug1         50                 49                48
drug2         90                 87               80
drug3          40                43               42
```

I want to perform a t test comparing cell viability values of untreated with each of the drugs I used.

I tried to use a for loop but it did not work:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dataset)) {
   x = dataset["untreated",]
   y = dataset[i,]
   result<-t.test(x,y)
}
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive in what did not work?

Comment: it perform only one t.test comparing the "untreated" row to the last row

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dataset example from your post:

```
dataset <- data.frame(sample_01=c(100,50,90,40),
                      sample_02=c(120,49,87,43),
                      sample_02=c(110,48,80,42)
                      )
rownames(dataset) <- c("untreated", "drug1", "drug2", "drug3")
```

Your loop seems fine, there are only two modifications needed:

1st you should start the loop from `2` and not from `1` since you don't want to compare the first row with itself (untreated).

2nd you should store your results in a list, not overwrite a variable called "results" because then you will rewrite it each time inside a loop and in the end will only have the answer for the last row.

Here are the modifications:

```
results <- list()
for (i in 2:nrow(dataset)) {
  x <- dataset["untreated",]
  y <- dataset[i,]
  results[[i-1]] <- t.test(x,y)
}
```

Now you can obtain the p-values:

```
> sapply(results, getElement, "p.value")
[1] 0.008337497 0.033407617 0.006107201
```

Alternatively to make things easier you might consider using a package:

```
library(matrixTests)
> row_t_welch(dataset[-1,], dataset["untreated",])
      obs.x obs.y obs.tot   mean.x mean.y mean.diff     var.x var.y   stderr       df  statistic      pvalue  conf.low  conf.high alternative mean.null conf.level
drug1     3     3       6 49.00000    110 -61.00000  1.000000   100 5.802298 2.039996 -10.513075 0.008337497 -85.50204 -36.497961   two.sided         0       0.95
drug2     3     3       6 85.66667    110 -24.33333 26.333333   100 6.489307 2.985027  -3.749758 0.033407617 -45.04393  -3.622734   two.sided         0       0.95
drug3     3     3       6 41.66667    110 -68.33333  2.333333   100 5.840472 2.093283 -11.699968 0.006107201 -92.41964 -44.247023   two.sided         0       0.95
```